# InvalidOperationException thrown from StreamWriter on WriteAsync scheduled on ExclusiveScheduler

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm scheduling a series of writes to a StreamWriter in quick succession on an ExclusiveScheduler like so:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
        {
            await _writer.WriteAsync(responseJson.ToString() + ',');
            await _writer.FlushAsync();
        }, 
        _cancel.Token, 
        TaskCreationOptions.None, 
        _writeNetworkScheduler.ExclusiveScheduler);
```

If I schedule writes quickly enough, I get an InvalidOperationException. After doing some digging, it looks like the writer hangs on to the last async operation performed to throw this exception. This is the only way I'm scheduling writes on this Writer.

If I change to using the non-async versions of the methods, things execute fine, but I'd like to understand why I'm getting this exception when I'm already awaiting the previous write and flush.

Comment: Hmmm. Is it because the method I'm feeding the TaskFactory types to an async void (and so returns control after the first write call)? If so, how should I be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is because `StartNew` does not understand `async` methods. You [need to unwrap them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/), as such:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
    {
        await _writer.WriteAsync(responseJson.ToString() + ',');
        await _writer.FlushAsync();
    }, 
    _cancel.Token, 
    TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
    _writeNetworkScheduler.ExclusiveScheduler).Unwrap();
```

(also, use the `DenyChildAttach` option for tasks intended to be consumed by `await`).

Comment: How does this ensure that the task scheduler waits for the previous task to complete? Like, if I never await the task returned from this method, it'll still try to schedule multiple writes, won't it?

Comment: I assumed that the calling method does `await` the returned task. If it does not, then `ExclusiveScheduler` will not work for what you want it to do. Check out `ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow instead.

Comment: +1, but could you clarify why `DenyChildAttach` is important here? I'm familiar with the reasonings in [Stephen Toub's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/09/22/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5.aspx), but I still can't see why an alien attached child task might break the logic here, tks.

Comment: Actually, the `Unwrap` does make the `DenyChildAttach` unnecessary in this scenario, since the wrapped task is never exposed.